# Mechanical Engineering and Mathematics Double Major

Tags: mathematics, university, engineering, major

I am entering University this next semester as a mechanical engineering student, but I need advice about potentially getting a second major (most likely in mathematics).

Here are the main points regarding my situation:

- I haven't yet committed to getting a double major and won't need to make the decision until, at the earliest, my sophomore year
- I've always been fascinated with mathematics, which was actually part of my decision to major in mechanical engineering since it's largely based on math
- I'm going into college with 30 hours already, with 8 of them being inapplicable in most majors except as free electives.
- I've already researched and found out I could do both majors (mechanical engineering and mathematics) by taking 18 hours this semester, 17 for the next three, 16 for the next two, and 15 and 12 for the last two respectively. However, I'm also taking at least one 3-hour class each semester online to lighten the load
- I've gotten a couple of decent scholarships that have made expenses for these first 4 years to be fairly low (a little over 3k a semester), but most of these scholarships don't apply after 4 years.
- I'm hoping to participate in the club sports program as well as a couple of engineering clubs to help with my resume, but I may not depending on the workload. I'm also hoping to get an internship during the summer after my sophomore and junior year.

So I've been thinking about getting a second major in mathematics, but I'm also open to getting a second major or minor in something else, or just not doing it and focusing on engineering, but I want advice regarding the situation. Please feel free to ask for clarification and thanks for all the advice in advance!

Comment: Ask your academic advisor this question, please.

Comment: Is it necessary to do the 18 in your first semester? It may be better to start with 15 and then decide how to proceed after you have the lay of the land a bit more. But ultimately this comes down to how you prioritize your goals; there is no real question here that we can answer.

Comment: It’s impossible to provide a general answer to this question.  You need to discuss with your academic advisor(s) and consider their advice.

Answer (score 1):

*I've always been fascinated with mathematics, which was actually part of my decision to major in mechanical engineering since it's largely based on math*

This is not true.

Some of the best mechanical engineers, especially those involved in mechanical design, are fairly poor math students.

Of course there's more to mech eng than mech design. Common specializations are:

- Energy management - heat, mass and fluid transfer study as used by HVAC and process plant design engineers.
- Plant Management - tribology, reliability, failure mode analysis, maintenance scheduling, etc studies used by maintenance engineers/managers
- Energy Generation - mechanics and design of existing & alternative energy generation processes
- Biomechanics - mechanical engineering aspects of living systems, esp. of the human body, artificial limb joints, organ ducts, etc
- Nanomechanics - study of nanoscale mechanical systems
- Mechanics of materials used in engineering - mechanical metallurgy/materials science
- Engineering computation - modelling and numerical solution of complex mechanical engineering phenomena

I would not rate the standard of math used in mech eng to be too challenging - it's usually application of existing analytical/numerical solutions of differential equations. There is little discrete math and little scope for someone with a liking for pure math. In my opinion a typical electronic engineer would be a much more capable math student than a mech eng student.

Frankly I don't think that mech eng and math are a good combination and I feel that you should do a single major in either of these subjects. The high-class math analysis done within mech eng will be done by people with math major BS and a MS in things like math modelling, continuum mechanics, fluid dynamics modelling, etc.

On top of that good math students should be reflective while good mech eng students should be dynamic and practical. Yes, if the math comes easy you can sit down after a dynamic day at mech eng and maybe get the benefit of trade-offs. But that would be at the expense of having a normal student life: when your BS is done and you look back at college life you will regret neglecting the opportunity to have met so many interesting people at an important point in their & your lives. There is only so much time in the day.

I would advise choosing one of the two disciplines on the basis of (1) **which you would prefer not to lose**; and (2) **the type of people that ultimately you want to spend your working days with**.

Note that traditional mech eng jobs like mech design, plant management and energy management are fewer and fewer so that your stream has to be among the newer streams - biomechanical, energy generation, nano-mechanical systems, modelling.

Also be aware that some math graduates (especially those going into financial sector and social sciences modelling) are paid waaaaaaayyyyy more than mech eng graduates. Yet this is totally irrelevant to your decision, which must be based on what is **right for you** not the bank. Good luck.

Comment: I agree with most of the answer except the last para - "_math graduates are paid waaaaaaayyyyy more than mech eng graduates_". That's contrary to my knowledge. Anyway, +1.

Comment: I refer to those app math graduates going down the financial math/investment modelling route. In EU €100k including bonus is not unusual in Y1 post graduation for such people. Sure, I accept that math modellers in engineering roles, e.g. power generation, aerospace, pollution control, etc are usually pegged to engineers' salaries and have to acquire expertise through additional study to move up the pay ladder. Apologies for that. I was concerned that OP might be taken in by overpositive math professors trying to recruit him. Edited my answer.

Comment: I would say [Finite Element Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_element_method) combined with Mech Eng is probably one of the best choices for the OP. Of course, Probability/Stats in applied math makes money, but it doesn't seem to be aligned with OP's own interest.

Comment: @Nobody There's a lot of ex-mech engs going down the FEA route => large supply of FEA engs => mundane work + low salaries. Computational aerodynamics is a big and complex field and close to where his internship is. But really, it's for OP to feel his way towards the "right" work arena.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I did not know FEA Eng is that bad.